# What does 'topologically' generated mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, galois-theory

I heard ablolute galois group of finite field is 'topologically' generated by frobenius map.

I understand this sentence except for 'topologically', but what does 'topologically' exactly mean here?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Galois group of a field extension comes with a topology, on which you can find some good expositions on this site and elsewhere.

If $G$ is a topological group and $S$ is a subset of $G$, we say that $S$ topologically generates $G$ if the closure of the subgroup generated by $S$ is equal to $G$.

Note that Frobenius cannot possibly generate $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}/\mathbb{F}_q)$, which is uncountable and in particular not cyclic, so "topologically generates" is the best you can hope for.

Comment: Oh, I understood the definition of 'topologically generates', thank you so much. The Galois group $ Gal(Fq-/Fq)$ is isomorphic to $Z^$（pro finite completion of Z）, how can we formally prove $Gal（Fq-/Fq）$ is topologically generated?  （If this is not suitable for comment space, I'll ask again in another quesiton）.

Comment: @bellow Look up [Krull topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_group#Examples). The quick argument: If $\sigma\in G=Gal(\overline{\Bbb{F}_q}/\Bbb{F}_q)$ is arbitrary, and $U$ is an arbitrary neighborhood of $\sigma$, then there exists a natural number $n$ such that $U$ contains all the automorphisms $\tau\in G$ such that the restrictions of $\tau$ and $\sigma$ agree on $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$. But the restriction of $\sigma$ to $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$ is a power of the Frobenius. Hence $U$ contains a power of the Frobenius, meaning that $\sigma$ is in the closure.